# Has the GNU coreutils stat tool changed?

Tags: gnu, coreutils, stat

Has the GNU coreutils (8.6) version of `stat` changed? After a recent update, some scripts I wrote that call stat are not working as expected; in particular, I had been making use of `stat -c %Y "${filename}"`. This is supposed to return the time of last modification in the form of seconds since "Epoch". However, I could have sworn this used to take the form of a whole integer. However, I'm now getting output from this of the form `1287630625.956667227` rather than `1287630625`. Since Bash can't handle floating point arithmetic, this is a litttle annoying. Is this a deliberate change? Or a bug? Or has my memory gone fuzzy? I tried searching for information on this, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I wanted to come back and note that they've reverted to the old behavior for version 8.7 of coreutils, though if you want the decimal places, you can use, e.g., `stat -c $.5Y filename` to get 5 decimal places. Otherwise you get none.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[stat: print timestamps to full resolution](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=9069af45e691d1252c727da66aa4f3f3c7f1ea29) was committed to coreutils-8.6.

```
$ git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/coreutils.git
$ cd coreutils
$ git log -1 --grep=time -- src/stat.c
commit 9069af45e691d1252c727da66aa4f3f3c7f1ea29
Author: Eric Blake 
Date:   Thu Sep 30 16:42:13 2010 -0600

    stat: print timestamps to full resolution

    * src/stat.c (epoch_time): New function.
    (print_stat): Use it for %[WXYZ].
    * NEWS: Document this.
    * tests/touch/60-seconds: Adjust test to match.
    * tests/misc/stat-birthtime: Likewise.
$ git describe --contains 9069af4
v8.6~29
```

Comment: Thanks. One would have thought that for backwards compatibility they would have introduced an alternative notation and not replaced %[WXYZ].

Answer (score 6):

This was unnecessarily disruptive and was reverted for `coreutils` ≥ `8.7`.
Since then you need to specify `%.Y` etc to get the fractional part included